# How to add two Range<Index> together?

Tags: ios, swift, search, filter, range

so I am filtering data (all strings), and want to show the following:

1. The search words where the first letters contain your search (example. when searching *'Br'* I want to see all the words that begin with *'Br'* like Break, Broke,...)
2. The search words where the string contains the word (example. When searching 'Br' is shows all words containing 'br' in the word like 'groundbreaker').

I've got both of them to work separately (see `let found` and `let foundMore`), but now I want to merge both of them (first showing the search words where the first letter contains your search, after the ones where the string contains the word). Tried using the addition sign, but it gives the following error

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two 'Range?' operands

```
    extension SearchResultsController : UISearchResultsUpdating {
        func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController:     UISearchController) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
        let target = searchBar.text!
        self.filteredData = self.originalData.filter {
            s in
            let options = NSStringCompareOptions.AnchoredSearch
            let found = s.rangeOfString(target, options: options)

            let optionsMore = NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch
            let foundMore = s.rangeOfString(target, options: optionsMore)

            let allTogether = found + foundMore

            return (allTogether != nil)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ranges cannot be added together, because the result may not be a proper range when the two ranges do not intersect.

However, you do not need to add this, because in the end you compare the overall range to `nil`. This means that you can compare the two sides to `nil` individually:

```
return s.rangeOfString(target, options: NSStringCompareOptions.AnchoredSearch) != nil
    || s.rangeOfString(target, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil
```

> check 1. and 2., should be viewed like this, not a mix of both

Then you should filter twice, and append the second array to first one:

```
var filtered1 = self.originalData.filter { s in
    return s.rangeOfString(target, options: NSStringCompareOptions.AnchoredSearch) != nil
}
let filtered2 = self.originalData.filter { s in
    // Exclude results of the first search
    return s.rangeOfString(target, options: NSStringCompareOptions.AnchoredSearch) == nil
 && s.rangeOfString(target, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil
}
filtered1 += filtered2
self.filteredData = filtered1
```

Comment: Hi, this works BUT it doesn't filter my data the way I want to it (check 1. and 2., they should be viewed like this, not a mix of both). It's like I would want to do a .append on the end of the first array (if this makes sence)

Comment: @SoundShock That's also doable - please see the edit.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

For your case you can replace `+` with `??` so that if either range is non-nil it will be set as the value of `allTogether`. This is minimal code, but isn't necessarily the most obvious or easy to read. An explicit logical OR nil test is more obvious.

Comment: Hi, This was indeed an option I already explored, but in this case it doesn't filter my data the way I want to have it (first show the search words where the first letters contain your search (example. when searching 'Br' I want to see all the words that begin with 'Br' like Break, Broke,...)
The search words where the string contains the word (example. When searching 'Br' is shows all words containing 'br' in the word like 'groundbreaker').

Comment: thats because filtering and sorting are 2 different things, and you need to filter first and then sort afterwards

Answer (score 0):

If possible, can you can try this:

```
let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
indexSet.addIndexesInRange(NSMakeRange(0, 5))
indexSet.addIndexesInRange(NSMakeRange(10, 4))
indexSet.addIndex(5)
println(indexSet)
```

Then you can do your activity here:

```
indexSet.enumerateIndexesUsingBlock { (index, stop) -> Void in
    println(index)
}
```